# Give user write permissions based on meta data tag (s)

Tags: permissions, managed-metadata, metadata, user-accounts

Ex:

- The organisation do not have access to write back to AD
- Everybody (users) in a organisation have read permission on every document / library / site  etc.

Based on "something magic" (list / user permission / token ... ) is there a way to give write permission based on a meta data tag?

If a document got the tag "CAR" the user "X" got persmission to write to the document?

Sombody have mention:

- C2WTS
- itemReciever  (custom check ONLY when a documents gets open)
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X4rzQ6ufBnI

There is a third party that seems to have this:
-http://www.titus.com/software/sharepoint/metadata.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not available out of the box.

But you have a number of options:

**Put documents in folders with unique permissions**
If it's a single value that determines who can change the document then you can:

- Create a number of folders (one for each value)
- On each folder break permission inheritance
- Give the right people write access
- Place the documents in the right of these folders based on the value

**Unique Permissions**
If your world is more complex then you need code either an event receiver or a workflow which breaks inheritance on each item and assigns the right group of people the write access.
In this case be aware the performance degrades when you have a lot of unique permissions.

Comment: Is it possible to write a custom itemReciever that checks the persmission ONLY when opening a document?

Comment: No you can't react to opening a document. But you can create an event receiver which checks "permissions" when adding/updating a document